Is there a way to check which security update policy a Google Cloud Function is using (on the Google Cloud Console)?
According to this, Google Cloud functions can have either one of two security update policies:

Automatic updates (default) and
On deployment updates

On the Google Cloud console, is there a way to view which update policy my function is using?

Yes, It is possible to check the security update policy of Google Cloud Function in the console. Click enter to the Function Name. Select the details section of the function and check the Equivalent Rest.

-Functions with automatic security updates enabled will have the key automaticUpdatePolicy.
-Functions that update on deployment will have the key onDeployUpdatePolicy.
The example is shown in the image below.

For more information on the security policy of cloud function you can follow this document
